# referencing pipeline in DownloadPipelineArtifact Step with variable wont work?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have tried 2 different attempts to reference the correct pipeline when downloading specific artifacts via two different built in steps. and cannot seem to get it to work.

this first way, will error in the oddest way i have ever seen. the pipeline will show 'pending' when selecting the run itself, but when going back one level to view the pipeline as a whole it will show a red x as if the run has failed, but when trying to dig into it, i can get no output.

```
#attempt 1
- download: $(PIPELINE_NAME)
```

and. this second way will successfully download the package in <1sec.... meaning it isnt actually downloading anything. the next step will fail as no package is found.

```
              - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
                name: 
                displayName: 'Download artifact test'
                inputs:
                  buildtype: specific
                  project: <project name here>
                  pipeline: '$(PIPELINE_NAME)'  #this just doesnt work for some reason
                  runVersion: specific
                  runId: $(resources.pipeline.$(PIPELINE_NAME).runID)
                  downloadPath: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```

Is this just not meant to work? neither of these will resolve the variables and will fail. Anyone have any other suggestions? do these NEED to be hardcoded? or am i missing some syntax? We have several nearly identical micro-services that i would like to just share the same template between them if i could.

Comment: Have you publish the build artifact in previous pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [arguments document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops#arguments) of Download Pipeline Artifacts task, the value of pipeline parameter should be the definition **ID** of the build pipeline, not the source name. So this may be the reason that your parameter doesn't work.

To download artifact from another pipeline, **you don't need to specify pipeline resources**. This is my method of downloading artifacts from another pipeline:

Firstly, in my previous pipeline, I have a [Publish pipeline artifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops):

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

And then, in another pipeline, I have a [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops):

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '$(project)'
    definition: '$(pipelineID)'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
    pipelineId: '$(buildID)'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

**Tip:**
**You can click on "settings" above the task and fill in the information with UI if you don't need to use variables.** UI will produce picklists of projects, pipelines, ... that you can choose.

[image]

Comment: Is there a user-friendly way of getting the buildID variable value?

Comment: I found it (pipeline resources)